# RmiRegistry created multiple times when running unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, rmi

My Spring Boot app has a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class JmxRmiConfig {
    @Value("${jmx.rmi.host:localhost}")
    private String rmiHost;
    @Value("${jmx.rmi.port:1099}")
    private Integer rmiPort;

    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistry() {
        final RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setPort(rmiPort);
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setAlwaysCreate(true);
        return rmiRegistryFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("rmiRegistry")
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        final ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setObjectName("connector:name=rmi");
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(String.format("service:jmx:rmi://%s:%s/jndi/rmi://%s:%s/jmxrmi", rmiHost, rmiPort, rmiHost, rmiPort));
        return connectorServerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

I have two unit tests both annotated like this:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@Unroll
class ... extends Specification { ... }
```

(Unroll and Specification are both from spock.lang)

When I run them together using maven/surefire, the second test class fails, with this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rmiRegistry' defined in class path resource
>   [uk/ac/prospects/hedd/api/config/JmxRmiConfig.class]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use

It appears to be re-creating the RmiRegistry again for the second class, without destroying the first one.

Since I have other tests without @AutoConfigureMockMvc that run fine together, my hypothesis is that @AutoConfigureMockMvc is triggering the problem.

How can I get both tests to run together?

Comment: I am running into the same problem and I see no solutions have been offered. 
Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @EvanKairuz yes we solved this today while investigating other problems with tests not passing when run as a suite of tests. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following additional configuration to the surefire plugin resolved this problem for us.

```
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
```

Don't understand the issues 100%, but we added the above as the test suite was getting confused between Spring beans that were mocked in one test, but configured properly in another test. This also fixed the RMI bean problem. I think this gives a clean Spring context for each test.

Comment: Good job on figuring this one out. My team has abandoned the jmx work unfortunately, but I did test this change and see that now the JMX Connector Server is started and stopped for every test.
As an aside this caused our tests to take a lot longer, nonetheless thanks very much for posting your solution. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but think there may be a solution with the Spring Test Framework annotation @DirtiesContext : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-dirtiescontext